# how to add key name to array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr_type=array(
    "1"=>"A",
    "2"=>"B",
    "3"=>"C",
    "4"=>"D",
    "5"=>"E",
    "6"=>"F",
    "7"=>"G",
    "8"=>"H"
);
```

how to change key name and level change?

`$arr_type['1']['name'] = A;`

`$arr_type['2']['name'] = B;`

Comment: `array_walk($arr_type, function (&$value) { $value = ['name' => $value]; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$new_arr = array();

foreach($arr_type as $k => $v){
    $new_arr[$k]['name'] = $v;
}
```

---

Since this got chosen, I'm also adding @Mark Baker's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443842/how-to-add-key-name-to-array/34443862#comment56629570_34443842) using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) here:

```
array_walk($arr_type, function (&$value) { $value = ['name' => $value]; });
```

Comment: Thanks. I found my other problem. And I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In case one wants to keep the original array unchanged, this solution would also work:

```
$result = array_map(function ($value) { return ['name' => $value]; }, $arr_type);
```